# Tools or utilities to check correct Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, git

I am aware of tools like JSLint, but I'm not looking for style correctness, I need a tool or utility (preferably one that runs on Linux, bonus points for being in the ubuntu package manager) that can verify the syntactic correctness of a JavaScript file.

I just need to know that there are no syntax errors.

(Full disclosure, was going to put this check in a git commit hook, to ensure that syntactically incorrect JavaScript would not be committed. So it can be a style tool, but needs to be able to produce a "YES SYNTAX GOOD", or "NO SYNTAX BAD" result.)

Comment: I never used them to that end but minifiers normally return errors when applied on bad js files. I know [Google's Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) does that and you may call it from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you think JSLint doesn't verify syntax, but I think it does exactly what you want. Now, for my bonus points! :-)  Here is a quick example that should do everything you want, despite using JSLint.

```
sudo apt-get install spidermonkey-bin
wget http://www.jslint.com/fulljslint.js
mv fulljslint.js /home/admin/bin/js
```

then create /home/admin/bin/js/runjslint.js:

```
load('/home/admin/bin/js/fulljslint.js');
var body = arguments[0];
var result = JSLINT(body);
if (result) {
 print('YES SYNTAX GOOD');
} else {
 print('NO SYNTAX BAD');
}
print(JSLINT.report());
```

This file, when run using Spidermonkey, will check the syntax of Javascript data passed as a command line argument. You might not want that report at the end, thought it might be worth having for you to play with though.

Comment: I didn't mean literally YES SYNTAX GOOD, NO SYNTAX BAD, but amusing anyway :P

Comment: I figured the more complete the answer, the more likely I could get a little green check mark next to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

[acorn.js](https://github.com/marijnh/acorn/) is a really small javascript parser. It throws a javascript error when it encounters a problem.

Download acorn

```
curl https://raw.github.com/marijnh/acorn/master/acorn.js > acorn.js
```

Create a runner called acornIt.js with the following contents (requires node to be installed)

```
var acorn = require('./acorn');
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = process.argv[2];
var contents = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

try {
   acorn.parse(contents);
   console.log("YES SYNTAX GOOD");
} catch (e) {
   console.log("NO SYNTAX BAD");
   console.log(e); // See where the error occured
}
```

And run it

```
node acornIt.js someTestFile.js
```